# Error when installing Zope Interface 4.0.3 on Python 2.7 needed for Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, zope

New to Python and Scrapy. I need these modules apparently to run scrapy properly. I downloaded Zope interface as suggested and have been attempting to install using easy_install as per instructions on Scrapy. I'm running Windows 7 64 and first downloaded the 64 bit version of Pyton 2.7 and all modules including Zope. That didn't work, so I unistalled everything and downloaded the 32 bit versions, but I'm having the same problem. Clearly, I'm doing something very basic incorrectly. Would appreciate assistance.

This is what happens:
C:>easy_install zope.interface-4.0.3-py2.7-win32.egg

I get a whole bunch of results (which stackoverflow doesn't let me copy/paste even though I'm properly formatting it as code) that says at the end:

```
No local packages or download links found for zope.interface-4.0.3-py2.7-win32.egg
```

I know I need zope, because when I try and run srapy, I receive the following error (also other results):

C:>scrapy shell http://www.yahoo.com

`raise ImportError(required + ": no module named zope.interface.")
ImportError: Twisted requires zope.interface 3.6.0 or later: no module named zope.interface.`

As I said, I'm real new at this and having a tough time with all the modules and packages needed to get going.

Comment: Try following this installation guide: http://steamforge.net/wiki/index.php/How_to_Install_Scrapy_in_64-bit_Windows_7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

easy_install and pip install take package names, not the filename.

so the correct invocation would be

```
easy_install zope.interface
```

which will fetch the latest version. If you specifically want that version

```
easy_install "zope.interface==4.0.3"
```

You can usually find package names by googling, eg. pypi zope interface

Comment: I knew it was simple. Thanks. Experienced users sometimes don't appreciate how newbies get flumoxxed with the little things. On Scrapy's website all it says is: ◦zope.interface: download the egg from zope.interface pypi page and install it by running easy_install file.egg
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've spent an absurdly long time trying overcome the zope problems when installing scrapy and just found a solution!

I just followed step 7 here (as Talvalin suggested)
http://steamforge.net/wiki/index.php/How_to_Install_Scrapy_in_64-bit_Windows_7

Then, in my site-packages location I just changed the name of the egg file "zope.interface-3.8.0-py2.7-win-amd64.egg" to "zope". All worked fine after that.

Hope this helps somebody!